# Ignoring digits, blank spaces and read String input, using Character.isLetter & Character.isDigit

Tags: java, string, if-statement, character, letter

I have been stuck for quite some time. I would need to ignore digits entered, blank spaces and special characters like $^%##&! and just read the other letters a-z, using Character.isDigit & Character.isLetter.. I have tried using the both methods, it didn't work out for me.. Please advice..

The error:
[image: Img1]

The normal output (without spaces and digits) :
[image: Img2]

The expected output should be 438-5626 even when I entered 123$@GetLoan.. They should ignore the first few characters '123$@' and read only GetLoan..

Full Question: Write a program that prompts the user to enter a telephone number expressed in letters and outputs the corresponding telephone number in digits. If the user enters more than seven letters, then process only the first seven letters. Also output the – (hyphen) after the third digit. Allow the user to use both uppercase and lowercase letters as well as spaces between words.

```
public class Question3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String letters;
    char phoneDigit;

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter letters : ");
    letters = kb.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

        phoneDigit = letters.charAt(i);

        if (Character.isLetter(phoneDigit) == true) {

            if (i == 3) {
                System.out.println("-");
            } //If 

            if (phoneDigit >= 'A' && phoneDigit <= 'C'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'a' && phoneDigit <= 'c') {

                System.out.println("2");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'D' && phoneDigit <= 'F'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'd' && phoneDigit <= 'f') {

                System.out.println("3");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'G' && phoneDigit <= 'I'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'g' && phoneDigit <= 'i') {

                System.out.println("4");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'J' && phoneDigit <= 'L'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'j' && phoneDigit <= 'l') {

                System.out.println("5");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'M' && phoneDigit <= 'O'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'm' && phoneDigit <= 'o') {

                System.out.println("6");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'P' && phoneDigit <= 'S'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'p' && phoneDigit <= 's') {

                System.out.println("7");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'T' && phoneDigit <= 'V'
                    || phoneDigit >= 't' && phoneDigit <= 'v') {

                System.out.println("8");

            } else if (phoneDigit >= 'W' && phoneDigit <= 'Z'
                    || phoneDigit >= 'W' && phoneDigit <= 'z') {

                System.out.println("9");
            } // If
        } // If
    } // For loop

} //PSVM
```

Comment: Please don't show error messages using screenshots, enter it normally in the question description.

Comment: Also tell how it is not working, what is the expected output and what are the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Below fragment is probably the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    phoneDigit = letters.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(phoneDigit) == true) {
```

You are taking first 7 characters, and printing only the ones that are letters. So for input string `123getloan` you will iterate over `123getl`, and then `isLetter` will reject `123`, so your program later will deal only with `getl`.

To iterate over only 7 letters you would need to change it to increment `i` only if given character is a letter e.g. by doing the below:

```
int i = 0;
for (char phoneDigit : letters.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isLetter(phoneDigit)) {
        i++;

        // other ifs here

        if (i == 3) {
            System.out.println("-");
        }
    }
    if (i >= 7) {
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Fixed problem mentioned by @Andreas

Comment: Hi krzyk, thanks for your quick reply.. It really did ignore the digits, but it did not read from g onwards... The 123 are considered as char0 ,1 ,2... I need the 1st character to start at 'g'...

Comment: Answer is almost correct. First half is great, but if you only increment `i` when `isLetter(phoneDigit)` is true, then you will loop forever if a non-letter is encountered. You need `for (int i = 0, count = 0; i < letters.length() && count < 7; i++)`, with conditional increment of `count` inside the loop.

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your help. I have tried and the output is almost correct! For the hyphen (-) I put a If statement, if (i == 3)  { println(" - ") } But they consider the 1,2,3 to be char 0,1,2.. ![https://postimg.org/image/m9x5z3bif/]

Comment: @krzyk +1, however with the order of execution you show, the `-` is printed between 2nd and 3rd digit, and it has to be between 3rd and 4th digit. Change to `i == 4` *or* swap `i++` with `if` *or* swap `if` with comment.